# Generating Object name at run-time

Tags: vb.net

I have a Player class in my code and I want to initialize its object by creating the name of the object as Player_1, Player_2 ...  . I simply want to generate object name at runtime in string variable "Object_name" and value of Object_name should be like Player_1, Player_2, Player_3...

```
Private Function SaveTo_Player_Class_Object(ds)
    For j As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        Dim Object_name As String = "Player_" + Convert.ToString(Player_Class.Total_Players + 1)
        Object_name = New Player_Class()
        Object_name.Name = ds.Tables(0).Rows(j)(0).ToString()
        Object_name.District_State_Nation = ds.Tables(0).Rows(j)(1).ToString()
        Object_name.Year_Of_Birth = ds.Tables(0).Rows(j)(2).ToString()
        Object_name.Weight = ds.Tables(0).Rows(j)(3).ToString()
    Next
End Function
```

But I am getting an error in VB editor "Value of Type Player_Class cannot be converted to string"

After I change As String to As Object

```
Private Function SaveTo_Player_Class_Object(ds)

    For j As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        Dim Object_name As Object = "Player_" + Convert.ToString(Player_Class.Total_Players + 1)
        Object_name = New Player_Class()
        Object_name.Name = ds.Tables(0).Rows(j)(0).ToString()
        Object_name.District_State_Nation = ds.Tables(0).Rows(j)(1).ToString()
        Object_name.Year_Of_Birth = ds.Tables(0).Rows(j)(2).ToString()
        Object_name.Weight = ds.Tables(0).Rows(j)(3).ToString()
    Next
End Function
```

In this case, Object Name is Object_name, not Player_1

My both version of code are not working.

Comment: Is this VB.NET, VBA, or C#?

Comment: Of course the second one is not working since you declare the variable as Object and you give it a string value

Comment: Code is in VB.NET

Comment: Total_Players is Integer variable define in Player_Class  assume it Total_Players = 1

Comment: I want each Object_Name should be replaced by its value i.e Player_1

Comment: @RameshKumar - Please edit your question. Don't add code in the comments.

Comment: @RameshKumar - Please also add `Option Strict On` to the top of all of you code files. That will help you to become a better programming almost instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining `Object_name` as a `String`. In VB.NET (or C#) when you define a variable as a specific type that type cannot change. It must always, in the current scope, be a `String`.

So when you try to assign `New Player_Class()` to `Object_name` then VB.NET is telling you that you cannot convert it to a `String`.

I have the feeling that you're trying to define a new variable with name `Player_1`, `Player_2`, `Player_3`, etc, so that you can use that name elsewhere in your code.

You can't do that.

VB.NET is a statically-typed language. Every variable that you want to use must be defined at compile-time. You cannot define new variables at run-time.

What you can do, though, is use a array, or a list, or a dictionary, or many other types to hold your player variables at run-time.

You can do something like this:

```
Private Function SaveTo_Player_Class_Object(ds As DataSet) As List(Of Player_Class)
    Dim players = New List(Of Player_Class)
    For j As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        Dim p = New Player_Class()
        p.Name = ds.Tables(0).Rows(j)(0).ToString()
        p.District_State_Nation = ds.Tables(0).Rows(j)(1).ToString()
        p.Year_Of_Birth = ds.Tables(0).Rows(j)(2).ToString()
        p.Weight = ds.Tables(0).Rows(j)(3).ToString()
        players.Add(p)
    Next
    Return players
End Function
```

Now you can call `Dim players = SaveTo_Player_Class_Object(ds)` and then you can access each player like `players(0).Name`.

Alternatively you can use a `Dictionary(Of String, Player_Class)` like this:

```
Private Function SaveTo_Player_Class_Object(ds As DataSet) As Dictionary(Of String, Player_Class)
    Dim players = New Dictionary(Of String, Player_Class)
    For j As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        Dim p = New Player_Class()
        p.Name = ds.Tables(0).Rows(j)(0).ToString()
        p.District_State_Nation = ds.Tables(0).Rows(j)(1).ToString()
        p.Year_Of_Birth = ds.Tables(0).Rows(j)(2).ToString()
        p.Weight = ds.Tables(0).Rows(j)(3).ToString()
        players.Add("Player_" + Convert.ToString(Player_Class.Total_Players + 1), p)
    Next
    Return players
End Function
```

Now you can call `Dim players = SaveTo_Player_Class_Object(ds)` and then you can access each player like `players("Player_42").Name`.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks For Help, got the answer.